# connecting socket to a specific path

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

i have a path localhost:3000/home to which i want to pass messages via socket.io.

My js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require("path");
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('*', function (req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/Public'));
});

app.use('/home',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/Public')));

//app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + 'index.html'));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (data) {
  console.log(data)
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
   });
    socket.on('another-message', function (data) {
    socket.emit('not-news', { hello: 'world' });
  });
});
 


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

My html file

```
<html>
<h1>working</h1>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var ioPath = "";
  iopath = '/' + 'home'+ '/socket.io'
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { path : iopath});
  //var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('connect',function(){
    socket.emit('message',{ 'msg' :'Hello server'}); 
    //socket.emit('message', 'Hello server');
  });
   socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id ="target" action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

i get the following error in browser console :"GET http://localhost:3000/home/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LA2Fcjf 404 (Not Found)"

Please correct me.

Comment: Servers listen on ports, not on paths.

Answer (score 2):

Try something this

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http,{ path: '/home/socket.io'});
```

Comment: Try adding more text to make this feel like an answer :) Perhaps explaining how this might help OP?

Comment: This answer is terse but correct.
Adding the parameter `{ path...}` makes the webserver serve `socket.io.js`  on an alternative path.
Here the client will be able to get the script at  http://<server>/home/socket.io/socket.io.js'